# X4500 harddrive to device name mapping

Tags: solaris, boot, sun

I have to manage a couple of X4500 boxes. We have some automated install script (using SUNWjet) which assumes root disk is c5t0d0 and mirror at c5t4d0. 
These are the only disks the X4500 can boot from

But on machine that failed. After long fiddling it turned out on this machine the boot disk is c4t0d0 (and c4t4d0). So it installed on one disk and could not find the boot block when rebooting :-[ "bad PBR sig"

So anybody knows how to change this mapping? I want to have this consistent between machines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the level of [firmware](http://jacksonjstrong.blogspot.com/2008/09/preparing-to-install-suns-x4500.html), apparently, that causes the change in behaviour.

Comment: Yeah, that seems to be the reason. The one server has a different Firmware version. I googled a lot for this and even asked Sun for Support. 

Thanks alot.